# Best practice to implement viewmodel classes?

Tags: class, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Suppose you have a model made up of these classes:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public EnumState State {get;set;}
    ...other properties
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJobGrade> EmployeeJobGrades { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeJobGrade 
{
    public int JobGradeId {get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId {get; set; }
    public JobGrade JobGrade {get; set; }
    public Employee Employee {get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate {get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate {get; set; }
}

public class JobGrade 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJobGrade> EmployeesJobGrades{ get; set; }
}

public class Group 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JobGrade> JobGrades{ get; set; }
}
public class Service 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

An Employee may have different JobGrades. Each JobGrade belog to a Group. An Employee may be associated to many Services.

Now you have to create a Detail view for Employee that have to display these fields:

- Employee serial number
- Employee name
- Employee email
- current job grade name
- current job grade start date
- current job grade's group name
- list of names for services associated to the employee

Which is the most appropriate approach to implement an EmployeeDetailViewModel, based on your experience?

a) add only properties for the fields to display in the view?
Something like this:

```
public class EmployeeDetailViewModel
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState {get;set;}
    public string CurrentJobGradeName { get; set; } 
    public string CurrentJobGradeStartDate { get; set; }
    public string CurrentJobGradeGroupName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Services { get; set; }
}
```

b) aggregate other ViewModel classes even if you don't have to use all of their fields.
Something like

```
public class EmployeeDetailViewModel
{
    public EmployeeViewModel Employee {get;set;}
    public JobGradeViewModel CurrentJobGrade { get; set; }  
    public IEnumerable<ServiceViewModel> Services { get; set; }
}
```